# Hyperledger Fabric: Endorsement policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

It's possible in Hyperledger Fabric to specify that all peers in an organization must endorse the transactions?

I'll try to explain better what I am doing. Starting from the examples in the fabric-samples repository, I want to realize a scenario in which I have two separate nodes (on two different VM): on the first one I have my first peer (peer0.org1.example.com), the orderer and the fabric-ca; on the second one I have my second peer (peer1.org1.example.com).

For now, I am been able to do that: I install the chaincode on both peers and instantiate it on the channel, so I can (from both the peers on the two VMs) send transactions. But when I instantiate the chaincode, I can only say that only one of the two peer is needed to endorse the transactions (I am instantiating it with something like: *docker exec cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n mychaincode -l java -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.member')"* ).

Can I specify that both peer0.org1.example.com and peer1.org1.example.com must endorse all transactions? In my configuration they both belong to the Org1 organization, I wouldn't want to split them in two ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. With the syntax OutOf(), you can set how many peers needs to sign.
For example:

```
OutOf(1, 'Org1.member', 'Org2.member')
OutOf(3, 'Org1.member')
OutOf(2, 'Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member')
```

You can check more of this sintax [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax).

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your answer! So, in my case I should use the second one, am I right? 
I'll try!

Comment: Yes, should be: `OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member')`

Comment: Ok, I've done some tests. By using OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member') I don't solve my problem: I always get an "ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE".
I solved using AND(''Org1MSP.member', 'Org1MSP.member'). 
They should be equivalent, but it work.